# Read JSON file content from google cloud storage bucket

Tags: angularjs, json, google-cloud-storage

Objective is to get the data (Basically a List of movies) from Google Cloud Bucket and show it in my HTML page.

Front End will be a Angular Project , which will make a REST API call to google cloud bucket to get the data. I have uploaded JSON file (with a list of movies)in my bucket .

SO when tried to call REST API

```
 var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/movie-database/o/document.json';
  $scope.datas =  $http.get(url).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('resp',resp);
        var data=  resp.data.result;
 });
```

Which gives response , basically it gives matadata

```
 {
     "kind": "storage#object",
     "id": "movie-database/document.json/1499855046872299",
     "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/movie-database/o/document.json",
     "name": "document.json",
     "bucket": "movie-database",
     "generation": "1499855046872299",
     "metageneration": "2",
     "contentType": "binary/octet-stream",
     "timeCreated": "2017-07-12T10:24:06.839Z",
     "updated": "2017-07-12T10:52:17.553Z",
     "storageClass": "REGIONAL",
     "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2017-07-12T10:24:06.839Z",
     "size": "630",
     "md5Hash": "OCQlXAqft2KWcvQh4f3B9Q==",
     "mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/movie-database/o/document.json?generation=1499855046872299&alt=media",
     "crc32c": "nG5vPg==",
     "etag": "COuZorrDg9UCEAI="
    }
```

So what is the way to get the json data as a response ?

Comment: monda, can you please help me I am new to front-end. How can I integrate GCS to my AngularJS app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the "mediaLink" attribute on the metadata? That's what you need. The pattern will go:

```
`https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/movie-database/o/document.jso?alt=media`
```

Alternately, you could use the pattern:

```
`https://storage.googleapis.com/movie-database/document.json`
```

That second one is shorter, but using from JavaScript will require setting up a CORS policy on the object. The first pattern will work regardless.

Comment: Getting this error: 

Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object movie-database/document.jso.

I'm new to Google Cloud Storage, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Whoops, I wrote "jso" and not "Json". Try it with your real.filename.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough I'm still getting a `Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to {file}` when using `&alt=media`, I'm guessing we have it set up for this, but is there any way I can provide credentials in an ajax call for instance?

Comment: The caller needs some sort of credential. If it's running on an end user's web browser, you'll either need to make the file anonymously readable, or you'll need to vend some sort of view permission to the end user. A signed URL is a popular choice for this.